# Expand all dropdown links at the same time using chromes dev tools?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I have been using Chrome's developer tools today and have learned how to automatically get to the bottom of an infinite scroll on a blog. At the bottom of each post is a drop down menu I would like to expand for each post - is it possible to use the console to expand these links all at the same time?

[image]

I have found the code for the button inspecting with developer tools: The below appears to be the code that controls the button: specifically 'aria-hidden="true"' which i believe is triggering the drop down box to show.

```html
<button class="org-update-analytics__toggle-details-btn t-14 t-black--light t-bold" aria-expanded="false" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-367="367">
      Show stats
      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-down-icon" class="org-update-analytics__toggle-button-icon" size="small"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M8,9l5.93-4L15,6.54l-6.15,4.2a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.69,0L1,6.54,2.07,5Z" class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path></svg></li-icon>
    </button>
```

I changed this to read aria-expanded="true" but im just a beginner so not sure what to do next. Unfortunately I can not share a link as its behind an admin login - but can provide full code and images if helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive answer without a link to the page, but my guess is that each of these buttons has the `org-update-analytics__toggle-details-btn` class. So if you run something like this in the Console:

```
const selector = '.org-update-analytics__toggle-details-btn';
document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(node => {
  node.click();
});
```

You might be able to expand each dropdown.